# How to prove that a real solution to this algebraic equation exists ? (roots of a given multivariate polynomial)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

The equation is

$$(y_0z_1-y_1^2) \sum\limits_{i=0}^2 c_i x_i=x_0x_1z_1+y_0\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 c_i y_i\right)\left(c_0y_1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 c_i z_i\right) -y_1x_0\left(c_0y_1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^2 c_i z_i\right) -y_1x_2\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 c_i y_i\right)$$

The unknown are $c_0,c_1,c_2$, the other variables are fixed on the real line under the following assumptions: $y_0\geq 0, z_1 \geq 0, y_0z_1-y_1^2 \neq 0$.

Is there a real solution to this equation under those general assumptions ? It looks like the equation corresponds to finding the real root(s) of a polynomial of degree $2$ in $c_0,c_1,c_2$. Is this possible ? I only need to know that a real solution exists, not necessarily compute it.

The challenge is hidden in the square roots we take to arrive at a solution: for example if we fix $c_0=0=c_1$, we get a quadratic equation for $c_2$, but then nothing guarantees that $c_2$ is real.

If there are no real solutions under those assumptions, can you find what extra (minimal) assumptions should the variables satisfy to get a real solution ?

Comment: Where does this problem come from ?

Answer (score 1):

Under the given assumption, the equation has no real solutions iff $$y_0=x_0z_1-x_1 y_1+x_2 y_1=x_0z_2- x_2 y_1+x_2y_2=0\mbox{ and }x_0x_1z_1\ne 0.$$

Let us show this. I did routine calculations with Mathcad, so we skip them.

Impose first a restriction $c_2=0$. Then the initial equation becomes a quadratic equation with respect to $c_1$ whose discriminant is a quadratic polynomial with respect to $c_0$ with the highest coefficient $y_0^2(y_0z_1-y_1^2)^2$. So if $y_0\ne 0$ then for sufficiently big $c_0$ the discriminant is non-negative and so the initial equation has a real solution.

If $y_0=0$ then $y_1\ne 0$ and the initial equation reduces to a linear equation

$$(x_0z_1-x_1 y_1+x_2 y_1)c_1+(x_0z_2- x_2 y_1+x_2y_2)c_2= x_0x_1z_1/y_1.$$

Comment: The part you skipped is precisely the part I am interested in, could you develop it more ? Ultimately, I would like to understand how to do that case in order to generalise it: you see the sums go to $2$, I would like them to go to $n$. But first, the case $n=2$, so how did you find those conditions ?

Comment: @W.Volante [The skipped part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT2p1.png).

Comment: I feel stupid, I do not see where you proved that the equation has no real solutions iff $$y_0=x_0z_1-x_1 y_1+x_2 y_1=x_0z_2- x_2 y_1+x_2y_2=0\mbox{ and }x_0x_1z_1\ne 0.$$

Comment: @W.Volante An equation $ax+by+c=0$ has no real solutions $(x,y)$ iff $a=b=0$ and $c\ne 0$.

Comment: But what about the case where $c_2 \neq 0$, $y_0 \neq 0$ ? It is the "iff" that is surprising me. I understand that indeed, if (the negative of) the conditions you wrote are satisfied, we get real solutions. But you are also claiming that if we have real solutions, then those conditions must be satisfied, how is that true ? Thank you a lot for your input, it's very helpful!

Comment: @W.Volante If the conditions I wrote are satisfied (which cannot happen when $y_0\ne 0$) then the initial equation reduces to an equation $x_0x_1z_1=0$, which has no solutions because $x_0x_1z_1\ne 0$.